# Unable to Adjust Column Width Using Tree Grid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningtreegrid, slds-styling-hooks

I am using a tree grid and in the column properties I have a column with the `type: 'action'` which renders a dropdown list with the list of `typeAttributes` I've specified. The issue I'm encountering is I cannot seem to adjust the column width for that specific column. I've tried setting the `initialWidth: 250` and I've also tried setting `min-column-width="250"` attribute on the `lightning-tree-grid`. These attributes apply to the other columns, but not to the column of the dropdown.

Tree Grid:

```
            <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                <lightning-tree-grid
                    columns={gridColumns}
                    data={data}
                    key-field="id"
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    min-column-width="250"
                ></lightning-tree-grid>
```

JS

```
get gridColumns() { 
    return [
        { 
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Product Name', 
            fieldName: 'productName', 
            initialWidth: 250 
        
        },
        {
            label: "Status", 
            fieldName: "status", 
            initialWidth: 250,
            type: "action",
            typeAttributes: { rowActions: [
                                                { name: "live", label: "Live" },
                                                { name: "inprogress", label: "In Progress" },
                                                { name: "contracted", label: "Contracted" },
                                            ]}
        },
    ];
}
```

The column looks like this when it renders:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "action" type is always minimum width. It is used to present actions that a user can take for the row, such as editing or deleting a record. Ordinarily, no label is provided for this column type.

For example, this is how it might look when looking at a list of fields (highlighting added):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox that makes sense. As an alternative, would it be possible to set the row color based on the selection of the dropdown using `onrowaction`? For example, live is green, in progress is yellow and contracted is red. Could the individual row colors be manipulated?

Comment: @user1718612 You can't highlight the entire row (e.g. a background), but you can add an `iconName` in `cellAttributes` to display an icon from the standard library.